# How to update tha app's data without the need to update the app version? (android app)

Tags: android, eclipse, updates

Can someone please tell me how to update the app's data without the need to update the app?
For example, if I have a song's app and I whold like to add another song, how do I do it using the internet or something without the need to update the app's version? Is it in the data-base? should I write a code that allowing to do it before? (I am working with Eclipse if it matters...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok at the first you have to upload your songs in your server for example ( to make it available to all users ).
Then your have to download the links to your mobile phone by JSON ( there is another mthods like XML but I used JSON ) ..

After download the links by JSON .. just parse them then you have the link of your song in your app ! so now do your job.

This is a link of tutorial how to download json data to your android :
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

FYI : first try to read about JSON (Java Script Object Notation ).